# 2 days ago when i open my ether wallet i notice that all of my ether is stolen

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

2 days ago when i open my ether wallet i notice that all of my ether is stolen

about 25 ether

my addres is 0xbE50d343BC815C424a5bD3abf7B3046fe4f491c9

and the hacker addres is 0x1896172cF718A14680BC62c0dB3a0223408cc10b

please help me??/

really all of my ether is gone?

Comment: The amount was transferred on this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x73964df361bed0ce32ec1b98ae29fed4d4bd7503f7efe594af3b895257bb40d7 . Only your wallet can allow such a transfer.

Comment: If you think your the victim of a scan I urge you to report to https://etherscamdb.info/scams/ so you can help others avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You lost all of your ether and there is **NO** way to recover it.
Next time, double-check ICO sites if they are real and do not give your keystore / private key to people.

Report phishing sites at https://etherscamdb.info/report